# Having problems with opencv projectPoints

Tags: c++, opencv, vision

The projected image doesn't change whenever I change the down_range variable. All the projected points have the same Y value when projected, and it remains that way despite change every variable (x, y, z, pitch, roll, and yaw). Is there something I am missing?

Relevant code

```
//  Vision Target Coordinates
vector<Point3f> objectPoints = getObjectData();

// Create camera matrix for Kinect with focal length found online
Mat cameraMatrix = setCameraMatrix();

vector<Point2f> projectedPoints(objectPoints.size());

//3D Rotation and Translation vectors
Mat rvec1(3,1, cv::DataType<double>::type);
Mat tvec1(3,1, cv::DataType<double>::type);

Mat rvec2(3,1, cv::DataType<double>::type);
Mat tvec2(3,1, cv::DataType<double>::type);

//Initialize to zero
rvec1 = Scalar::all(0);
tvec1 = Scalar::all(0);
rvec2 = Scalar::all(0);
tvec2 = Scalar::all(0);

// Create an image to display projected points
Mat img(height, width,  CV_8UC3);

//get inputs from user, CR, DR, UP, pitch, roll and yaw

tvec1.at<double>(0, 0) = -cross_range*12;   // Xpos (in)
tvec1.at<double>(1, 0) = -down_range*12;    // Ypos (in)
tvec1.at<double>(2, 0) = -up_range*12;      // Zpos (in)
rvec1.at<double>(0, 0) = -pitch*CV_PI/180;;  // X rot (rad)
rvec1.at<double>(1, 0) = -yaw*CV_PI/180;   // Y rot (rad)
rvec1.at<double>(2, 0) = -roll*CV_PI/180;    // Z rot (rad)

projectPoints(objectPoints, rvec1, tvec1, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, projectedPoints);

vector<Point3f> getObjectData()
{
vector<Point3f> points;

points.push_back(Point3f(-31.0, 10.0, 0.0));
points.push_back(Point3f(31.0, 10.0, 0.0));
points.push_back(Point3f(31.0, -10.0, 0.0));
points.push_back(Point3f(-31.0, -10.0, 0.0));
points.push_back(Point3f(-27.0, 6.0, 0.0));
points.push_back(Point3f(27.0, 6.0, 0.0));
points.push_back(Point3f(27.0, -6.0, 0.0));
points.push_back(Point3f(-27.0, -6.0, 0.0));
points.push_back(Point3f(-103.5, 25.69, 0.0));
points.push_back(Point3f(-41.5, 25.69, 0.0));
points.push_back(Point3f(-41.5, -3.31, 0.0));
points.push_back(Point3f(-103.5, -3.31, 0.0));
points.push_back(Point3f(-99.5, 21.69, 0.0));
points.push_back(Point3f(-45.5, 21.69, 0.0));
points.push_back(Point3f(-45.5, 0.69, 0.0));
points.push_back(Point3f(-99.5, 0.69, 0.0));
points.push_back(Point3f(41.5, 25.69, 0.0));
points.push_back(Point3f(103.5, 25.69, 0.0));
points.push_back(Point3f(103.5, -3.31, 0.0));
points.push_back(Point3f(41.5, -3.31, 0.0));
points.push_back(Point3f(45.5, 21.69, 0.0));
points.push_back(Point3f(99.5, 21.69, 0.0));
points.push_back(Point3f(99.5, 0.69, 0.0));
points.push_back(Point3f(45.5, 0.69, 0.0));

return points;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing Euler rotation, that is the mistake. 
Convert to [Rodrigues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) as OpenCV has nothing to do with Euler.